# Google Tag Manager custom timer event

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I would like a Javascript timer set up to send the user's time on page to Google Analytics. For the user's first interaction (landing page) we would like the timer to send a event:

- Every 1 second to 10 seconds
- Every 2 seconds to 30 seconds
- Every 3 seconds to 1 minute
- Every 24 seconds to 5 minutes
- Every 60 seconds to 15 minutes
- Every 90 seconds to 30 minutes

This should result in a maximum of 70 events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can setup a event tag and trigger it on timer event. Here is how trigger will look like http://take.ms/MDMEJ.